# Javascript Regex: validating a double

Tags: javascript

i need regex to validation numbers between 0.00 to 50.00 only !
that's mean 50.01 invalid number.

Can you help me

thanks

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the greater-than and less-than operators and want to use something else?  You're basically asking how to use a hammer to tighten a bolt.  Wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Yes I have a reason that's i keep it to my self . I know this function

Comment: Keeping your reasons to yourself is an excellent response.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: actually , I'am beginner in JavaScript . i have 24 text field . i have to create 24 functions   and call them 24 time ???? this is tired !!!!! for this reason i need Regex to do it !  because i can add it in one field in my tools and run it !!

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the number without a regular expression:

```
function validate(num) {
    var parsed = parseFloat(num);

    return (!isNaN(parsed) && parsed >= 0 && parsed <= 50.00);
}

alert(validate(-0.00001)); // false
alert(validate(0));
alert(validate(50));
alert(validate(50.00001)); // false
alert(validate('not parseable')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to go with [@Fenton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797796/javascript-regex-validating-a-double/46797857#46797857), but just in case:

```
^([0-4][0-9]|[0-9])\.\d{2}$|50.00$
```